# Sql group by counts

Tags: sql, group-by, count

I have one table , which contain following columns

```
CampName -- Camp Name 
CampId -- Camp Code
CouponCode -- Coupon Code
IsClaimed -- Boolean flag saying if a coupon is claim or not . True or False
```

This table contain all coupons . A coupon is used if the Isclaimed flag is set to true . The default value of this col is False

Now i need to create another table

```
VoucherRegister: 

CampaignName 
CampaignCode
VoucherUsed --> Number of voucher of a specfic campaign which are used 
VoucherUnUsed --> Number of voucher of a specfic campaign which are unused
```

any idea on how should i create it

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: please provide sample table if not output;

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generic method would use conditional aggregation:

```
select CampName as CampaignName,
       CampId CampaignCode,
       sum(case when IsClaimed then 1 else 0 end) as VoucherUsed
       sum(case when IsClaimed then 0 else 1 end) as VoucherUnUsed
from my_table  
group by CampName, CampId;
```

There may be simpler ways to express this, depending on the database you are using, but the above should work in any database.

Answer (score 0):

due the fact your IsClaimed column is boolean  you could sum the 1 and group by CampName, CampId

```
select CampName CampaignName
  ,CampId CampaignCode
  , sum(IsClaimed) VoucherUsed
  , sum(NOT IsClaimed) VoucherUnUsed
from my_table  
group by CampName, CampId
```

Comment: I am using sql server 2005. This is the internal server inside salesforce.

Comment: The above solution didnt work as expected , however i change the sql and now its working

Comment: Select 
 T1.CampId AS Campaign_No
 ,T1.CampName AS Campaign_Name
 ,(Select Count(T11.CampId) From LocalVouchers T11 where T11.IsClaimed = 'True' and T11.CampId=T1.CampId ) AS Voucher_Used
 ,(Select Count(T12.CampId) From LocalVouchers T12 where T12.IsClaimed = 'False' and T12.CampId=T1.CampId) AS Voucher_Unused
From
 LocalVouchers T1
Group by 
 T1.CampId
 ,T1.CampName

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select cmpname,campid,
(select sum(couponcode) from tablename group by campname where Isclaimed='IsTrue'  ) 
VoucherUsed,
(select sum(couponcode) from tablename group by campname where Isclaimed='IsFalse' ) 
VoucherUnused 
from tablename group by campname,Campid;
```

Comment: do i need to use sum or count

Answer (score 0):

my approach

```
 Select 
T1.CampId AS Campaign_No
,T1.CampName AS Campaign_Name
,(Select Count(T11.CampId) From LocalVouchers T11 where T11.IsClaimed = 'True' and T11.CampId=T1.CampId ) AS Voucher_Used
,(Select Count(T12.CampId) From LocalVouchers T12 where T12.IsClaimed = 'False' and T12.CampId=T1.CampId) AS Voucher_Unused
```

From
    LocalVouchers T1
Group by 
    T1.CampId
    ,T1.CampName

is a combination of above solution